# Load a HTML page (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I've never used Javascript before, so it's a bit confusing. I have a decent knowledge of HTML and some in C#.

Anyhow...I'm building a website and I'm trying to do a script that opens up a different html document if it is for example, Chrome, Internet Explorer etc. The thing is I don't know how to load the specific html document for each detection. I've already have a script that makes it detect the kind of browser you're using.

Code:

```
<script language="Javascript">

    var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
</script>
```

Comment: As a sidenote, strike that, as a BIG note, doing stuff based on browser is considered bad practice, and will often times lead to a lot of problems. Feature detection is almost always the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.get():

```
$.get('test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

For more info, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways, each has its own advantages and disadvantages. 
But as commented, it's not a good practice to "do stuff" based on the browser.

**1. Ajax:** 

    You can use [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to dynamically load html content based on the browser.

**2. Redirect** 

    Redirect to the right page based on the browser.

**3. Using css to display the right content** 

    You can hide all the irrelevant information (using display:none / visibility:hidden)
    and display the right one based on the browser.